# How to Change the Kerberos Default Ticket Lifetime

Tags: kerberos

Our KDC servers are running either Ubuntu Dapper (2.6.15-28) or Hardy (2.6.24-19).  The Kerberos software is the MIT implementation of Kerberos 5.  By default, a Kerberos ticket lasts for 10 hours.  However, we'd like to increase it a bit (e.g. 14 hours) to suit our needs better.  I had done the following but the ticket lifetime still stays at 10 hours:

1. On all the KDC servers, set the following parameter under "[realms]" in `/etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` and restarted the KDC daemon:

   ```
   max_life = 14h 0m 0s
   ```
2. Via "kadmin", changed the "maxlife" for a test principal via "modprinc -maxlife 14hours ".

   "getprinc " shows that the maximum ticket life is indeed 14 hours:
   Maximum ticket life: 0 days 14:00:00
3. On a Kerberos client machine, set the following parameters under [libdefaults], [realms], [domain_realm], and [login] in /etc/krb5.conf (everywhere basically since nothing I tried had worked):

   ```
   ticket_lifetime = 13hrs
   default_lifetime = 13hrs
   ```

With the above settings, I suppose that the ticket lifetime would be capped at 13 hours.  When I do `k5start -l 14h -t <principal>`, I see that the end time for the "renew until" line is now 14 hours from the starting time:

```
Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
04/13/10 16:42:05  04/14/10 02:42:05  krbtgt/<realm>@<realm>
 renew until 04/14/10 06:42:03
```

"-l 13h" would make the end time in the "renew until" line 13 hours after the starting time.

However, the ticket still expires in 10 hours (04/13 16:42:05 - 014/14 02:42:05).

Am I not changing the right configuration file(s)/parameter(s), not specifying the right option when obtaining a Kerberos ticket, or something else?

Answer (score 13):

Turns out that I also had to change the "maxlife" parameter for the service principal as well.  Specifically, I had to do "modprinc -maxlife 14hours krbtgt/[REALM_in_CAPS]" to get the lifetime increased to 14 hours.

To sum up, the ticket lifetime is the *minimum* of the following values:

- `max_life` in `kdc.conf` on the KDC servers.
- `ticket_lifetime` in `krb5.conf` on the client machine.
- maxlife for the user principal.
- maxlife for the service principal "krbtgt/[REALM_in_CAPS]" => What I had missed!
- requested lifetime in the ticket request. For example:

  - `k5start -l 14h`
  - `kinit -l 14h`
- `maxlife` for the AFS service principal "afs/[realm_in_lower_case]", if you want to increase the lifetime of your AFS token.

Mystery solved!

Comment: what other lifetime settings are involved when the user principal is in a different realm than the service principal and there is a one-way trust from the service realm to the user's realm?

Comment: can you provide your full example @user40497?

Comment: For the users of Heimdal, only changing maxlife for the principals are enough (unless you set it in the .conf)