# Give linux service user access to Kerberos NFS share

Tags: nfs, kerberos, service

I am running a NFSv4 server and a client on two raspbian buster distributions. I use Kerberos to secure the NFS share.

On the NFS client, I run the gitea service with git user, which is started on boot. I would like to store the git repositories on the NFS share, so the git user will need to access it.

When I login to git user and execute `kinit` I can access the share without issue.

**Is there a way that the gitea service automatically ask a Kerberos ticket and renew it so the service can access the NFS share without my intervention ?**

I did some research, I have some ideas in mind but not sure what's the best way to achieve it.

- I could run a cron that regularly run a `kinit`.
- This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/742386/automatic-kerberos-ticket-renewal-indefinitely) talks about SSSD (which I didn't know about)
- I could manually do an initial `kinit` and [set a very long ticket lifetime](https://serverfault.com/questions/132123/how-to-change-the-kerberos-default-ticket-lifetime) but it is not a good practice in a security point of view.

(I am new to Kerberos and NFS so they may be poorly configured but it works)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically two alternatives:

- running everything as **root**, since root uses the machine credentials,
- create a **client keytab** for your user.

In order to use the second solution you have to locate the default location for client keytabs:

```
piotr@bialykiel:~$ krb5-config --defcktname
FILE:/etc/krb5/user/%{euid}/client.keytab
```

and create the keytab using `kadmin`:

```
ktadd -k /etc/krb5/user/1234/client.keytab yourprincipal@YOUR.DOMAIN.ORG
```

Whenever a `GSS-API` application such as **rpc.gssd** will not be able to access your credential cache, it will create a new one using the keytab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will learn a bit more about keytab and use this solution.

Comment: You already have a keytab with the machine's credentials (`/etc/krb5.keytab`). Client keytabs are similar and contain an equivalent of the user's password: if someone else reads them, you must change the password.

Answer (score 0):

The answer "client keytab" goes into the right direction. But I couldn't make this work on its own. But with gssproxy it works like a charm. See https://github.com/gssapi/gssproxy/blob/main/docs/NFS.md for details.

Comment: In my case, gssproxy was already installed, *just* had to put the keytab at `/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/%U.keytab` per the client_keytab config line in `/etc/gssproxy/99-nfs-client.conf`